# Generate and display html table with user data from wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**Update: With the help of the answerer below I figured out how to do this. Basically I used a WP Query to get users and their user metadata and I sorted and placed the data in a for each loop in a table.**

I'm new to PHP and I need some help. Basically I want to create a leaderboard with different user data. I want to display it in an html table.

This is kinda what i want:

Username        GamiPress Points       Time since last login

And I want the table to be populated with these data amongst others automatically. I want two versions one that is sorted with the 15 users who have the most points and one that sorts on the 15 users that logged in last.

Can someone point me to the right place on how I can best implement this?

I basically want to create the GamiPress Leaderboard add-on that I, unfortunately, can't afford, but with some extra fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple steps to do if you want to achieve this:

1) Add meta field to your users, so you can store the points. For example you can use "Advanced Custom Fields" plugin for this.

2) Write a function for adding points to this field. Define when this function will be fired.

3) Query the users ordered by that meta value and display it (get_users($args) might be useful).

4) For the Last-Login value you can use a plugin (google Wordpress Last Login) and write another Query and order results by that meta field. You can also write this by your own, here is a link I found: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-show-users-last-login-date-in-wordpress/

I don't know if this is what you were looking for.

Or did you want to see an example code how you use a wp query and display data in html table?